# How to add publish and preview button on post type listing?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created  custom post type 'card'. Now i want to add publish and preview buttons in custom columns in post type listing. i have added a column for publish but don't know how to add the button.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJQYk.png

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend here is to use the plugin Admin columns for Wordpress. It is available here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/

This may not allow you to add a button but it will allow you to easily modify the columns that are displayed